# How can send value from class to main class flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have Two Class in same page first Class name (Colords) and second Class
name(ColorDott) I want to pass value from second Class to first class use InkWell
onTap

//Pass value from here

and retrieve the value in the Class Colords extends StatefulWidget{

// receive value here
}
... I made a lot of attempts, but unfortunately it was unsuccessful ,All attempts were
showing me a phrase null.

```
 class Body extends StatefulWidget{
 final Product product;

  Body({Key key,  this.product}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Sa createState() => Sa();
  }
  class Sa extends State<Body> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView(
  children: [
    ProductImages(product: widget.product),
    TopRoundedContainer(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ProductDescription(
            product: widget.product,
            pressOnSeeMore: () {},
          ),
          TopRoundedContainer(
            color: Color(0xFFF6F7F9),
            child: Column(
              children: [
               
                Colords(product: widget.product),
             
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      ),
      ],
      );
    }

    }
```

.Colords class

```
   class Colords extends StatefulWidget{
   final Product product;
   //retrieve value here

  Colords({Key key,this.product}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Colr createState() => Colr();
   }
 class Colr extends State<Colords> {
 final FirebaseAuth  firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
 int numOfItems = 1;
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return Padding(
  padding:
  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),

   child:Column(
     children:[   Row(
   children: [
   ...List.generate(
     widget.product.colors.length,
         (index) => ColorDott(
       color: widget.product.colors[index],
       //  isSelected: index == selectedColor,

       count:index ,

     ),
   ),
  Spacer(),
  RoundedIconBtn(
    icon: Icons.remove,
    press: () {
      if (numOfItems > 1) {
        setState(() {
          numOfItems--;
        });
      }
    },
  ),
  //SizedBox(width: getProportionateScreenWidth(7)),
  Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0 / 2),
    child: Text(
      numOfItems.toString().padLeft(2, "0"),
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
    ),
  ),
  RoundedIconBtn(
    icon: Icons.add,
    showShadow: true,
    press: () {
      setState(() {
        numOfItems++;
      });
    },
    ),
    ],
   ),
 // Expanded(),
    Row(
    children: [
    Expanded(
     child:TopRoundedContainer(
       color: Colors.white,
       child: Padding(
         padding: EdgeInsets.only(
           left: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.15,
           right: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.15,
           bottom: getProportionateScreenWidth(40),
           top: getProportionateScreenWidth(15),

         ),

         child: DefaultButton(
           text: "Add To Cart",
           press: () {
             setState(() {
              // widget.message='hgjh';
               print(widget.message.toString());
             });

           },
         ),
       ),
     ),
   )
  ],
),
     ]
   ),
);
}

}
```

ColorDott class

```
class ColorDott extends StatefulWidget{

@override
Colre createState() => Colre();
}
class Colre extends State<ColorDott> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      setState(() {
    //send value
      });
    },
      );
 }

}
```

thank you.

Comment: Please format your code properly, it's unreadable and disrespectful towards the people trying to help you.

Comment: @Lulupointu I edited post please re read it.

Answer (score 0):

I sloved by using sharedpreference